# MsBuild build bits but deliver web.config per environment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

Is it possible to create a build with VS2012 (and TFS2012), based on a changetset id, that delivers a set of binaries (web) and a set of web.configs per enviroment ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a build with VS2012 (and TFS2012), based on a
>   changetset id

Yes queue a new build, when the confirmation window appears, goto the parameters tab and under GetVersion enetr the changeset you want to build for, you may have to enter a C or a CS infornt, i.e. for changeset 999 c999 or cs999.

> that delivers a set of binaries (web) and a set of web.configs per
>   enviroment ?

Your binaries 'should' be target environment agnostic so you should be able to build once, deploy many times. your config files will depend on how you set them up, if you use the transform mechanism your configs will be created based on your Build configration. if you do your transforms a different way, you could add a post build task to copy the configs 'n' amount of times and then do a find replace type action to enter your environment specific config into each file